# Unexpectedly long service activating on systemd boot

Tags: systemd

I am using `systemd-analyze plot` to analyze the time services took to run on system start. There is a fairly simple oneshot service, `update_sysfs_cpu_permissions.service`, which takes unexpectedly long (755ms), moreover, the majority of time is spent in the Activating state, not Active.

The contents of the service file:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/update_sysfs_cpu_permissions.service
[Unit]
Description=Give the group `cpu_tuners` permissions to write to the files /sys/.../cpufreq/policy*/* if the `root` user can write to them

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
# For every file of mode rw-r--r-- change mode to rw-rw-r-- and owners to root:cpu_tuners (instead of root:root)
# mindepth and maxdepth are to identify we only want to change files inside policy* (though, it's not a very strong constraint and could be replaced with something stricter)
ExecStart=/usr/bin/find /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -perm 644 -exec /bin/sh -c 'chown root:cpu_tuners "$1"; chmod 664 "$1"' _ {} \;

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Running the service manually doesn't take much time:

```
$ time sudo systemctl start update_sysfs_cpu_permissions.service

real    0m0.155s
user    0m0.019s
sys 0m0.010s
$
```

The complete plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPh93.jpg

What does it mean for a service to be in the activating state? Why does it take it so long to run on boot?

Comment: Try removing `User=root`, as this may have some poorly documented side-effects.

Comment: @meuh, nope, no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it take it so long to run on boot?

Impossible to say without a more detailed trace (e.g. bootchart) of the boot process, but *my guess* is that during boot it is competing with other services for CPU – and possibly also for **disk I/O,** as it needs to load the `/bin/find`, `/bin/sh`, `/bin/chmod`, and `/bin/chown` executables from disk into memory.

> moreover, the majority of time is spent in the Activating state, not Active.

That's by design – Type=oneshot services have *no* 'Active' state by default. The entire purpose of a Type=oneshot service is to be in 'Activating' state while all of ExecStart= runs, so that only once the ExecStart= command has finished will the 'start' job complete.

> What does it mean for a service to be in the activating state?

'Activating' means that the unit has been invoked but is not yet "ready" for dependency and ordering purposes. For example, if you take a database server daemon, it may spend a few moments starting up, establishing its sockets, replaying journals, etc. – during which time the process is running, but not yet accepting client connections, meaning that any other services attempting to use it would fail.

So when a start job runs, it *waits* for the service to leave the 'Activating' state before proceeding with starting its dependents (if any). For example, httpd.service will wait in the queue while php-fpm.service is still 'activating'.

- For Type=forking, 'Activating' lasts until systemd sees the process "daemonize" (in the traditional way of forking or double-forking – more specifically, it lasts until the initial parent process *exits*, leaving its child to take over).
- For Type=notify, 'Activating' lasts until the process sends systemd a "READY=1" message over a designated socket or pipe.
- For Type=simple, there is no 'Activating' state by default (which people tend to forget when they rant about how "Type=simple is the true way of using systemd").
- For Type=oneshot, as in your case, 'Activating' **lasts until the service has done its thing,** i.e. until all of the commands in ExecStart= have completed.

(ExecStartPost= may also extend the 'activating' state, even for Type=simple, which can be used for some tasks that *must* be done after service startup before it's truly ready for use.)

So in this example, staying in 'Activating' state means that if another startup service had your unit listed in `After=`, it would be correctly delayed until /bin/find has finished and the permissions have indeed been updated.

> Try removing User=root, as this may have some poorly documented side-effects.

Setting User= *without* a PAMName= has only the effect of changing the UID/GID.